# how to assign explicit values randomly to a 2 d array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

i need to take the set  {0,.5, 1, 2 ,5}  and randomly fill a nxm matrix with the values , i figured i could just use this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create the grid
    final int rowWidth = 10;
    final int colHeight = 10;

    Random rand = new Random();

    int [][] board = new int [rowWidth][colHeight];

        //fill the grid
        for (int[] board1 : board) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board1.length; col++) {
                board1[col] = rand.nextInt(5);
            }
        }

        //display output
        for (int[] board1 : board) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board1.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(board1[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
```

and then just map each number {0,1,2,3,4} to {0,.5, 1, 2 ,5}  then re draw the matrix.... is there a better way to do this... how do i fill the matrix randomly with the specified numbers from the start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep an array holding the possible values, then pick one at random from that array:

```
final int rowWidth = 10;
final int colHeight = 10;
final double[] possibleValues = {0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0 ,5.0};

Random rand = new Random();

double[][] board = new double[rowWidth][colHeight];

for (double[] board1 : board) {
    for (int col = 0; col < board1.length; col++) {
        board1[col] = possibleValues[rand.nextInt(possibleValues.length)];
    }
}
```